# PDO mysql select query not executing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Why is this PDO not executing?

```
$statement = $db->prepare("select * from quest where id = :'"+$testno+"'");
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

echo "Q:".$row["questions"];
```

The "Q" is not echoed.

Comment: your query does not work because `:'"+$testno+"'"` you put the actual value but that must be a string which you will replace as in RichardBernards's response. Take a look

Comment: `+` is only for numbers. The string concatenation operator is `.`

Comment: @HerrSerker id is a number

Comment: But `"select * from quest where id = :'"` is not. `+` only works if both operands are numbers (or can be cast to one). In `PHP`!

Comment: @X10nD he said that because you use single quotes... come on man, you have 4K+ rep on SO... are you that n00b?

Comment: @AresDraguna My mistake, you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put named placeholder in prepared sql and bind it to desired value later:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("select * from quest where id = :id");
$statement->bindParam(':id', $testno, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

echo "Q:".$row["questions"];
```

Assuming id is integer, if not - replace `\PDO::PARAM_INT` with `\PDO::PARAM_STR`.

Comment: who defined $testno to be an integer?

Comment: @RichardBernards id is by convention an int :-?

Comment: @AresDraguna not particularly true... For some uses (like barcodes or the like), and id can very well be an alphanumeric or something else... My point was, this could not be deduced from the question with 100% certainty...

Comment: true that :) but you can't judge him for using it... he made an assumption and this is not incorrect, even if it is not 100% accurate

Comment: @RichardBernards you're correct, I've updated the answer, thanks! `$testno` implies it's a *number*, which implies it's an integer. Although it's still not 100% guarantee.

Comment: @AresDraguna and Stanislav; I'm sorry... One of my rolemodels follows the assertion 'Assumptions are the root of all evil'... Hence my nitpicking ;)

Comment: apologies to everyone, $testno is a number and not varchar.

Answer (score 1):

```
$statement = $db->prepare("select * from quest where id = :testno");
$statement->execute(array(':testno'=>$testno));
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

echo "Q:".$row["questions"];
```

Comment: Parse error: parse error in /Library/WebServer/Documents/file.php on line 20 :::: $statement->execute(array(':testno'=>$testno);

Comment: @X10nD Try again... in all my haste I forgot a bracket

Answer (score 0):

@X10nD, Simply use like below code... :)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM quest WHERE id = ?";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindParam(1,$testno);
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

echo "Q:".$row['questions'];
```